# How do I get data out of a custom function inside a custom binding handler into the viewmodel?

Tags: knockout.js, dynatree

I have a 3rd party control that is initialized in my view:

```
<!--<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: treeGroups }, groupTree: {}"></ul>/-->
```

with a custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.groupTree = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var tm = valueAccessor();
        var tmUnwrapped = tm();
        $(element).fancytree({
            minExpandLevel: 1,
            source: tmUnwrapped,
            lazyload: function (e, data) {
                data.result = datacontext.getGroupChildren('1111');
            },
            activate: function (event, data) {
                //logEvent(event, data);
                var node = data.node;
                // access node attributes
                alert(node.title);
            },

        })
    },
```

and all I'd like to be able to do is get the value I'm currently "alerting" in the "activate" method (node.title) into an observable in my viewmodel.  As the event is triggered sort of "inside" the treeview and handled by the activate method I can't see how I can get the node.title into an observable which is buried in the root viewmodel ($root.selectedTitle).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can you just reference the viewModel var that's passed into the `init` function, or is this a different context with no access to the root?

Comment: Yeah, it's a different context.  The structure is there's a master view/viewmodel. This has several observables exposed as sort of control variables including whether an article is selected in a list or not.  The master view has several subviews "composed" into it with `preserveContext: true` set in order to expose the $root or $parent properties back up the chain so I use things like "$root.isEditMode()" for example to determine whether to show/hide some edit fields.  Is there an equivalent of $root or $parent I can use in the activate method if I want to access the top level viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the custom binding automatically inherits the bindingcontext from the view its contained within, all that was needed was to access the $root model from the bindingcontext in the custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.groupTree = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var rootVm = bindingContext.$root;
    $(element).fancytree({
        minExpandLevel: 1,
        source: tmUnwrapped,
        lazyload: function (e, data) {
            data.result = datacontext.getGroupChildren('1111');
        },
        activate: function (event, data) {
            var node = data.node;
            rootVm.selectedArticle(node.title);
        },
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$root` or `$parent` psuedo variables are only available from within the context of data-binding.  However, you could pass those values into your custom binding with something like this:

```
//in your view
data-bind="groupTree: {rootVm: $root}"

//in your binding
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var settings = valueAccessor();
    var rootVm = settings.rootVm;
    //...
```

Comment: This will probably work if/when I can work out how to change my implied binding for an explicit durandal "compose" one as the way I'm doing it at present (2nd line of original question) is the knockout way and won't allow preservecontext to be used so I cannot access the root/parent viewmodel.

Comment: The 5th argument of the init and update functions of a customBinding is the bindingsContext.  You should be able to access $root via `bindingContext.$root`

Comment: It was an error on my part. The master view had two sections where the treeview was bound and the one I was testing didn't have "preservecontext: true" on it. As soon as I added that it all worked and I was able to access bindingcontext.$root.